# Am I committing a sin by performing fajr late due to nocturnal emissions?

Tags: salat

I do not masturbate, but sometimes I have unintentional nocturnal emissions (without having a dream), so I need to make ghusl before praying.  The problem is fajr time is very early, and at that time I barely manage to pray as I am secretly following Islam.  This is why I miss fajr whenever I ejaculate.  Today same thing happened, so I perform fajr 45 minutes after sunrise.  It happens at least once a month.

Am I committing a sin today?

I just cried in front of Allah (SWT) and even started to think that Allah does not need servant like me, and even started to think to leave Islam, but I realized it is shaytaan.

Also, today there are guest in my house, so my dad slept in the same bed as me.  After my dad wakes up to go for work, I will able to do salah.  So is that Allah's plan that I get an excuse of delaying salah because of ejaculation?